# Decoding JSON input in PHP

Tags: php, api, json, last.fm

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=XXXXX&api_key=XXXX&format=json');
$track_data = json_decode($json);


    foreach ($track_data as $data)
    {
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $text = $data->recenttracks->track->artist->mbid;
        }
        echo '<span>'; echo $text; echo '</span>';
    }
?>
```

This is the code I'm trying to use. The problem is: nothing shows up... What's wrong with it? :) Here's the JSON input (the content of the URL on file_get_contents): http://pastebin.com/NLHGMapT

Answer (score 1):

Track is an array:

```
$text = $data->recenttracks->track[0]->artist->mbid;
```

also, when you're in the foreach loop you don't need to use recenttracks:

```
$text = $data->track[0]->artist->mbid;
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! How can I get - for instance - 10 results? Now I only get the first object as output.

Comment: foreach($track_data as $data) { echo $data->track[0]->artist->mbid }